# SDL2 FillRect with SDL_Window issues

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm having issues trying to use SDL_FillRect with SDL 2.0

Here's my code:

```
bool running = true;

//Initialise SDL
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

SDL_Window *screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Test Game",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    640, 480,
    SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

while (running){
    SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, 0);
}

//Quit SDL
SDL_Quit();

return 0;
```

The error I'm getting is:

> 1>c:\users\ethan\desktop\c++ projects\another test with sdl\another
> test with sdl\main.cpp(16): error C2664: 'int SDL_FillRect(SDL_Surface
> *,const SDL_Rect *,Uint32)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'SDL_Window *' to 'SDL_Surface *'
>
> 1>          Types pointed to are
> unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or
> function-style cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SDL2, you should create a `SDL_Renderer` and use `SDL_RenderClear`.

If you really want to use `SDL_FillRect`, then you could call it on a separate `SDL_Surface` and then render that surface onto your window in 2 steps. The SDL2 migration guide talks about this stuff:
https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide

Answer (score 0):

`SDL_RenderPresent` is needed in order for your textures to be present in your render

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it a little to explain how it solves the problem?